# Does the forgetful functor from Lie algebroids to vector bundles have a right adjoint

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, lie-algebroids

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be an appropriate category of smooth spaces, and let $\mathrm{Vect} \colon \mathcal{S}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ be the functor sending a space to the category of vector bundles over it, with action on vector bundles via pullback.

Similarly, let $\mathrm{LieAlg} \colon \mathcal{S}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ be the functor sending a space to the category of Lie algebroids over it.

We can take the category of [Grothendieck lenses](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.02202.pdf) for each of these functors, and there is a forgetful functor $\mathsf{Lens}(\mathrm{LieAlg}) \to \mathsf{Lens}(\mathrm{Vect})$. Does this functor have a right adjoint? This would be something like the "cofree" Lie algebroid on a vector bundle.

So, specifically, for a vector bundle $E \choose B$, for any "dynamical system" on $E \choose B$, i.e. a choice of $TX \choose X$ with a lens to $E \choose B$, there would be a unique map of Lie algebroids $TX \choose X$ to the cofree Lie algebroid on $E \choose B$. So the cofree Lie algebroid is something like the "universal dynamical system on interface $E \choose B$" -- it can simulate any other dynamical system if you start it in the right state.

The intuition for why this might be the case is that if we work discretely in $\mathsf{Poly}$ (the category of Grothendieck lenses for the slice category functor $\mathsf{Set}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$), then I think the analogous category to $\mathsf{Lens}(\mathrm{LieAlg})$ is the category of polynomial comonoids (see Chapter 7 of the [poly book](https://topos.site/poly-book.pdf)). And this case, we do have an analogous construction; the cofree comonoid $\mathfrak{C}_p$ is kind of like the "universal discrete dynamical system" on the interface $p$.

Of course, this is not going to work in the category of finite-dimensional manifolds, but if we could get it to work in the category of [microlinear spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/microlinear+space) in a smooth topos, I would be happy.

Comment: Does the second theorem on page 2 of this paper help at all? https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03441v1 Maybe it's a simple case of what you're asking?

Comment: Name of @DavidWhite's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463260/does-the-forgetful-functor-from-lie-algebroids-to-vector-bundles-have-a-right-ad#comment1202714_463260):  [Nuiten - Homotopical algebra for Lie algebroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03441).

Comment: I think that result does say that forgetful functors for an appropriate notion of Lie algebroid over a fixed base have left adjoints, which is good news for their opposites to preserve limits; I think you’d be basically good to go if you could check that the reindexing functors preserve colimits, except that you probably don’t want to talk about Lie algebroids as actual vector bundles rather than in some more complete and cocomplete category as at the link